Python script for fast mouse circles running slow, how to speed up
I need to make this run faster, i.e. make circles with mouse very fast, and loop it until some predefined keyboard input. My initial code is below.
import pyautogui as pg
import math




resolution = pg.size()
radius = 100 # Circle radius
duration = 0.00000000000000000000000000001 # Duration of each move(mouse speed)
steps = 20 # Number of 'moves' or points on the circle

mid_x = resolution[0] / 2
mid_y = resolution[1] / 2

def GetXnY(angle):
    x = radius * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    y = radius * math.cos(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    return (x, y)

def DoACircle():
    angle = 0
    while angle  <= 360:
        x, y = GetXnY(angle)
        pg.moveTo((mid_x + x), (mid_y - y), duration = duration)
        angle = angle + (360/steps)
           
DoACircle()

It moves the mouse to slowly and I need to loop with keyboard interrup, not sure how to do it.

How fast do you want it to go, and what's the point?  Remember that you can only SEE updates at the monitor's frame rate.  If you run 60Hz, then you can't see anything faster than 1/3 second.

To increase speed you will need to increase the steps, reduce duration and there is a better way to optimise code.
OPTIMISATION:
    mid_x = resolution[0] / 2
    mid_y = resolution[1] / 2
    
    def GetXnY(angle):
        x = radius * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
        y = radius * math.cos(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
        return (x, y)
    
    def DoACircle():
        angle = 0
        while angle <= 360:
            x, y = GetXnY(angle)
            pg.moveTo((mid_x + x), (mid_y - y), duration=duration)
            angle += 360 / steps
    
    # Main loop that runs until 'q' is pressed
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        DoACircle()

This part is good, id adjust this alone if you want to change pace.
# Parameters
resolution = pg.size()
radius = 100  # Circle radius
duration = 0  # Duration of each move (mouse speed)
steps = 100  # Number of 'moves' or points on the circle

However, you will need to import:
import keyboard

EDIT: Forgot to add that you need to install the keyboard module:
pip install keyboard

EDIT 2: Instead of applying prior code import these modules:
import threading
import time

you could try testing a flag to stop the loop as well (optional)
stop_flag = False
then further down the code below the "def DoACircle():" insert:
def check_stop_key():
    global stop_flag
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            stop_flag = True
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)

Then add a separate thread:
key_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_stop_key)
key_thread.start()

The crux is this ending:
# Main loop that runs until 'q' is pressed
while not stop_flag:
    DoACircle()

key_thread.join()  # Wait for the key detection thread to finish

PS: Ultimately, your code should look like this:
import pyautogui as pg
import math
import threading
import time

# Parameters
resolution = pg.size()
radius = 100  # Circle radius
steps = 20  # Number of 'moves' or points on the circle
mid_x = resolution[0] / 2
mid_y = resolution[1] / 2

stop_flag = False

def GetXnY(angle):
    x = radius * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    y = radius * math.cos(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    return (x, y)

def DoACircle():
    angle = 0
    while angle <= 360 and not stop_flag:
        x, y = GetXnY(angle)
        pg.moveTo((mid_x + x), (mid_y - y), duration=0)
        angle += 360 / steps

def check_stop_key():
    global stop_flag
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            stop_flag = True
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)

key_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_stop_key)
key_thread.start()

while not stop_flag:
    DoACircle()

key_thread.join()

This should allow circles to be drawn when q is pressed. If it is still too slow, reduce the steps or possibly experimenting with OS-specific APIs

No this just makes it do a slower circle and does not exit with q press. I implemented what you wrote but not getting desired results. pls advise.

What sort of experimentation have you done besides STACK?
